# Restful service Curl command is working on unix but not in window

Tags: api, rest, curl

Can any one help to construct it so that i can use it window curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a Content-Type :

```
curl -d '{json}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://example.com
```